# How would you publish a message in ROS of a vector of structs?

Tags: c++, ros

I want to publish a vector of unknown length of structs that contain two integers and two strings. Is there a publisher and subscriber in ROS that can do this?

If not, I've been looking at the [tutorial of how to create custom messages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) and I figure I can make one `.msg` file containing:

```
int32 upperLeft
int32 lowerRight
string color
string cameraID
```

and another `.msg` file containing an array of the previous messages. But the tutorial does not give an example of how to use arrays, so I do not know what to put in the second `.msg` file. Furthermore, I am not sure how to even use this custom message in a C++ program.

Any tips on how to do this would be great!

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand a little bit what [@Sterling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766251/sterling) already explained...

If you have a project (and thus directory) called "test_messages", and you have these two types of message in `test_messages/msg`:

```
#> cat test.msg 
string first_name
string last_name
uint8  age
uint32 score

#> cat test_vector.msg 
string vector_name
uint32 vector_len         # not really necessary, just for testing
test[] vector_test
```

You can then write this C++ code:

```
#include "test_messages/test.h"
#include "test_messages/test_vector.h"

...

  ::test_messages::test test_msg;

  test_msg.age          = 29;
  test_msg.first_name   = "Firstname";
  test_msg.last_name    = "Lastname";
  test_msg.score        = 79;

  test_pub.publish(test_msg);


  ::test_messages::test_vector test_vec;

  test_vec.vector_len    = 5;
  test_vec.vector_name   = std::string("test vector name");

  for (int idx = 0; idx < test_vec.vector_len; idx++)
  {
      test_msg.age          = 50;
      test_msg.score        = 100;
      test_msg.first_name   = std::string("aaaa");
      test_msg.last_name    = std::string("bbbb");

      test_vec.vector_test.push_back(test_msg);
  }

  test_vector_pub.publish(test_vec);
```

Comment: can we use aggregate initialization from a braced initialization list for ros message structures

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your first msg is called MyStruct. To have a msg that is an array of MyStructs, you would have a .msg with the field:

```
MyStruct[] array
```

Then in the code you make a MyStruct and set all the values:

```
MyStruct temp;
temp.upperLeft = 3
temp.lowerRight = 4
temp.color = some_color
temp.cameraID = some_id
```

Then to add MyStructs to an array your array in the second .msg type, you can use push_back (just like with std::vector):

```
MySecondMsg m;
m.push_back(temp);
my_publisher.publish(m);
```

Comment: It said that push_back is not a member of m ?? why ?

Comment: Yes, it should be `m.array.push_back(temp)`