# How to publish and subscribe 2D string array/lists with ROS?

Tags: python, arrays, ros

I have this problem: I need a node to publish a matrix/2-D array of strings (or a 2D list of strings), the array is

```
sherd_1::link goHome0
sherd_2::link goHome0
sherd_3::link goHome0
sherd_5::link goHome0
sherd_6::link goHome1
sherd_9::link goHome1
sherd_10::link goHome2
sherd_11::link goHome1
sherd_12::link goHome0
sherd_13::link goHome2
```

Following [How to publish 2D lists with ROS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62271661/how-to-publish-2d-lists-with-ros) I figured out to write two custom messages,

one is `sherd_array.msg`

```
string[] sherds
string[] homes
```

and with this, I have no problem to publish and subscribe

then I try to define `matrix.msg` this way

```
sherd_array[][] data
```

but when I try to build it with `catkin_make` I get this error

```
genmsg.base.InvalidMsgSpec: braccio_moveit_gazebo_noetic/custom_msgs/msg/matrix.msg: invalid field: Currently only support 1-dimensional array types: custom_msgs/sherd_array[][]
make[2]: *** [braccio_moveit_gazebo_noetic/custom_msgs/CMakeFiles/_custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix.dir/build.make:70: braccio_moveit_gazebo_noetic/custom_msgs/CMakeFiles/_custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix] Errore 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1023: braccio_moveit_gazebo_noetic/custom_msgs/CMakeFiles/_custom_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_matrix.dir/all] Errore 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Errore 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

if I try to build the `matrix.msg` this way

```
sherd_array[2] data
```

this way it seems that the node publishing the message has no problem, but when I try to subscribe to the topic with matrix message the node which publishes crashes and in its terminal I get this error message

```
line 60, in serialize    length = len(val1.sherds)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sherds'
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

EDIT
if i use rospy.loginfo on the msg built for the matrix_msg I get the correct output

```
[INFO] [1697191139.662418, 201.596000]: data:
  - ['sherd_1::link' 'sherd_2::link' 'sherd_3::link' 'sherd_5::link'
 'sherd_6::link' 'sherd_9::link' 'sherd_10::link' 'sherd_11::link'
 'sherd_12::link' 'sherd_13::link']
  - ['goHome0' 'goHome0' 'goHome0' 'goHome0' 'goHome1' 'goHome1' 'goHome2'
 'goHome1' 'goHome0' 'goHome2']
```

EDIT
the answer of nogabemist below worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROS 1 does not natively support multi-dimensional arrays in custom messages. You can try this hacky solution.

Define your sherd_array.msg:

```
string[] sherds
string[] homes
```

Then, define your matrix.msg:

```
sherd_array[] data
```

In your publisher, create and fill the message:

```
import rospy
from custom_msgs.msg import sherd_array, matrix

rospy.init_node("matrix_publisher")
pub = rospy.Publisher('matrix_data', matrix, queue_size=10)

# Populate the data
mat_msg = matrix()
array_msg_1 = sherd_array()
array_msg_1.sherds = ['sherd_1::link', 'sherd_2::link', ...]
array_msg_1.homes = ['goHome0', 'goHome0', ...]

array_msg_2 = sherd_array()
array_msg_2.sherds = [...]
array_msg_2.homes = [...]

mat_msg.data = [array_msg_1, array_msg_2]

pub.publish(mat_msg)
```

In your subscriber:

```py
import rospy
from custom_msgs.msg import matrix

def callback(data):
    sherds_1 = data.data[0].sherds
    homes_1 = data.data[0].homes

    sherds_2 = data.data[1].sherds
    homes_2 = data.data[1].homes

    # Process the data ...

rospy.init_node("matrix_subscriber")
sub = rospy.Subscriber('matrix_data', matrix, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

you're trying to serialize a numpy array directly. When dealing with ROS messages, always ensure that the message data types and structures align with what you've defined in your custom message files.